# I can't use OpenCL on Dell XPS-L702X!

Tags: 22.04, dell, nvidia-geforce

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed and up-to-date.
My X.org driver works great.

However, I cannot use OpenCL for Johntheripper.
It gives me this message:

```
Error: No OpenCL-capable platforms were detected by the installed OpenCL driver.
Error: No OpenCL-capable devices were detected by the installed OpenCL driver.
```